# Error on changing stroke or strokeWidth of rectangle, circle and Image in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am facing an error while changing stroke color or stroke width of Rectangle, Circle and Image. Each time I change those values border become exponentially big.

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
obj.set("stroke", stroke);
obj.set("strokeWidth", strokeWidth);
canvas.renderAll();
```

I am using this code to set these properties.

[Image 1 shows the circle I added to canvas.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptajm.png)

[Image 2 shows the increased border after I change stroke color.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHxvP.png)

Comment: Update this happen only when I try to set strokeWidth

Comment: Controls go crazy is I try to resize image as well

Answer (score 4):

Use `parseInt()` method instead of set its value directly.

```
obj.set("stroke", parseInt(stroke));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try setting the padding to 5-10px.

```
obj.set("padding", '10');
```